# i18next loop over imports for multiple translation files?

Tags: react-native, localization, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

Using `i18next` & `react-i18next` in a React Native application to handle localization.

We have a node script that runs before the app builds to fetch these from an API and generates the correct folder paths and json files based on all language and translation file keys.

Our folder structure for our translations looks like this:

```bash
| src
| public
    | scripts
    | locales
       | en-US
           | common.json
           | auth.json
           | forms.json
           | ... etc
       | pt-BR
           | common.json
           | auth.json
           | forms.json
           | ... etc
       | ...
    |
```

There is about 12-15 json files per locale. Is there a better way so we don't have to manually import each one of them inside the i18n.ts file, as this is prone to error as we need to remember to add any additional json files that get created.

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import sportspage from '../../public/locales/en-US/sports-page.json';
import common from '../../public/locales/en-US/common.json';
import forms from '../../public/locales/en-US/forms.json';
import auth from '../../public/locales/en-US/auth.json';
// ...

import sportspageBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/sports-page.json';
import commonBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/common.json';
import formsBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/forms.json';
import authBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/auth.json';
// ...

i18n.use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        lng: 'en-US',
        fallbackLng: 'en-US',
        debug: true,
        defaultNS: 'common',
        react: {
            useSuspense: true,
        },
        resources: {
           'en-US': {
               common,
               forms,
               auth,
               'sports-page': sportspage,
               // ...
            },
           'pt-BR': {
               common: commonBR,
               forms: formsBR,
               auth: authBR,
               'sports-page': sportspageBR,
               // ...
            },
        },
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    });
export default i18n;
```

Can the backend plugin (`i18next-http-backend`) read from the locales folder without making the url call itself?

```js
i18n.use(initReactI18next)
    .use(Backend)
    .init({
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        // ...
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to use backend plugin (`i18next-http-backend`) read from the locales

Below is the updated i18n.ts file

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

import sportspage from '../../public/locales/en-US/sports-page.json';
import common from '../../public/locales/en-US/common.json';
import forms from '../../public/locales/en-US/forms.json';
import auth from '../../public/locales/en-US/auth.json';
// ...

import sportspageBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/sports-page.json';
import commonBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/common.json';
import formsBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/forms.json';
import authBR from '../../public/locales/pt-BR/auth.json';
// ...

export const defaultNS = 'common';
export const resources = {
           'en-US': {
               common,
               forms,
               auth,
               'sportsPage': sportspage,
               // ...
            },
           'pt-BR': {
               common: commonBR,
               forms: formsBR,
               auth: authBR,
               'sportsPage': sportspageBR,
               // ...
            },
        };
i18n.use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        lng: 'en-US',
        fallbackLng: 'en-US',
        debug: true,
        defaultNS,
        react: {
            useSuspense: true,
        },
        resources,
        ns: ['common', 'forms', 'auth', 'sportsPage', ...] //respective namespaces
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    });
export default i18n;
```

include an additional file since you are using typescript as index.d.ts

```
import '../../node_modules/react-i18next';

import { resources, defaultNS } from 'path/to/i18n';

declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    defaultNS: typeof defaultNS;
    resources: typeof resources['en-US'];
  }
}
```

Finally in the main sportPage.tsx file

```
import useTranslation from 'react-i18next';

const sportPage = () => {
  const {t} = useTranslation('sportPage');

  //...

  return {
    <div> { t('text') } </div>

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, although this is not an answer to the specified question, here is an improvement:

Instead of having multiple imports on the `i18n.ts` file:

```
import sportspage from '../../public/locales/en-US/sports-page.json';
import common from '../../public/locales/en-US/common.json';
```

One could use a single import:

```
import {sportspage_en-US, common_en-US} from '../../public/locales';
```

Just create a file `index.ts` in `/public/locales` with the following content:

```
export {default as sportspage_en-US} from './en-US/sports-page.json';
export {default as common_en-US} from './en-US/common.json';
```

Answer (score -1):

i18next-resources-to-backend may help: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#lazy-load-in-memory-translations

i18next-resources-to-backend helps to transform resources to an i18next backend. This means, you can also lazy load translations, for example when using webpack:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';

i18next
  .use(resourcesToBackend((language, namespace, callback) => {
    import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      .then((resources) => {
        callback(null, resources)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        callback(error, null)
      })
  }))
  .init({ /* other options */ })
```